# Can anyone tell me why this always executes the "else" part no matter the result of the "if" condition [node js]

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, if-statement

I have this route;

```
    router.get('/:specimenID', (req, res) => {
    const sampleID = req.params.specimenID;
    sql.connect(con, () => {
        const request = new sql.Request();
        const isValidSpecimenID = `SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS
        (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Interface WHERE
             Interface.SpecimenID =`+ sampleID +`) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`;
        const sqlQuery = `Select Interface.SpecimenID,
        Interface.Result,Interface.Range,Interface.ServerTime,
        Interface.AnalyzerCode from Interface 
        left join LabAnalyzerElements 
        on Interface.ElementID=LabAnalyzerElements.MappedElement 
        where Interface.AnalyzerCode = LabAnalyzerElements.AnalyzerID and Interface.SpecimenID =` + sampleID;
        request.query(sqlQuery)
        .then(results => {
            if (isValidSpecimenID == 1) {
                res.status(200).json({
                LISResults : results.recordset
            }); 
        }else {
                res.status(404).json({
                    Message: "invalid Specimen ID"
                });
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).json({
                message: err.message
            })
        })
    });
});
```

I want the response to be based on either the specimenID exist or Not but I always get an "invalid Specimen ID" response of the "else" block and I cant figure out why..

I tried the *isValidSpecimenID* variable query, in MSSQL Management Studio and it does return '0' if specimenID is not in the table and vice versa

It is a nodejs API using mssql and express server.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: **WARNING** the above code is wide open to SQL Injection. You should be fixing the code before you anything else.

Comment: Because you check the `isValidSpecimenID (query string) == 1` and that will result in false

Comment: @Larnu thanks for pointing that out. I will surely work on that

Comment: @BraveButter if i understand you, it means i should try and cast the results to interger? if so i will be gratefull if you can help with a code snippet. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You check your query string `SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Interface HERE Interface.SpecimenID = + sampleID + ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END == 1` which will return false.

Start your first query wait for the result and then check against your recordset.

Here is a code example:

```
router.get('/:specimenID', (req, res) => {
    const sampleID = req.params.specimenID;

    //Add some validation for sampleID here to prevent sql injections

    sql.connect(con, () => {
        const request = new sql.Request();

        const isValidSpecimenID = `SELECT 
                                    CASE WHEN EXISTS
                                    (
                                        SELECT TOP 1 1 
                                        FROM Interface 
                                        WHERE Interface.SpecimenID = ${sampleID}
                                    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`;

        const sqlQuery = `  SELECT  Interface.SpecimenID,
                                    Interface.Result,
                                    Interface.Range,
                                    Interface.ServerTime,
                                    Interface.AnalyzerCode 
                            FROM Interface 
                            LEFT JOIN LabAnalyzerElements 
                                ON Interface.ElementID=LabAnalyzerElements.MappedElement 
                            WHERE Interface.AnalyzerCode = LabAnalyzerElements.AnalyzerID 
                            AND Interface.SpecimenID = ${sampleID}`;

        request.query(isValidSpecimenID)
               .then(result => {
                    //check if your result is valid
                    if(result === isValid) {
                        return request.query(sqlQuery);
                    } else {
                        res.status(404).json({
                            Message: "invalid Specimen ID"
                        });
                    }
               })
               .then(results => {
                   res.status(200).json({
                       LISResults : results.recordset
                   });
               })
               .catch(err => {
                   res.status(400).json({
                       message: err.message
                   })
               })
    });
});
```

But after all you need to evaluate if you really need your first query, to me it looks like you dont have to check for `Interface.SecimenID` in the extra query. As long as your second query is correct and also the join between the two tables you shouln't get a row if there is no `SpecimenID`

**Reminder**

Please add some validaton for your input variable as @Larnu mentioned to prevent SQL injections

Comment: you are right about checking the `specimenID`. I introduce that to help those who will consume the endpoint to easily troubleshoot `specimenID` issues. Thanks you have been very helpful

Comment: Please do not edit my answer, instead you should update your question with your new attempt and then i can update my answer if needed. Do you really need two queries to check if your id is present. For now everything seems like you can archive that by only change your `LEFT JOIN` to a `RIGHT JOIN` and remove the first query completely.

Comment: I am sorry . I am new to stackoverflow . i appreciate your advice. thanks